# Caught fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_db_avail()?

Tags: php, geoip

The code is:

```
if (!geoip_db_avail(GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION)) 
        {
            //do this
        }
```

and it is throwing a:

```
Caught fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_db_avail()
```

in one of my applications.

On a test on another site on the same server using:

```
$country_name = apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME");
print "What: " . $country_name;

if (geoip_db_avail(GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION)) 
{
        print "NO!";
}
else
{
        print "YE";
}
```

It does not show the error but all the page prints is:

```
What: Pakistan
```

It does not print Ye or NO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual is your friend. This function is declared in PECL `geoip` extension which is installed on one of your servers but not on another.

You can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php) about installation and requirements.